# How can I start my Windows service on startup, and prevent users from stopping/restarting it?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

i have developed the window service. in this i want to start the service only when starting the computer. user can not start/stop/restart the service.manually these all thing are handle when user start the computer.

or lock the all properties from the user.all working done by coding when we start the computer.

Comment: Why do you want such service :), are you trying any hacking stuff???

Comment: @BreakHead, in a corporate environment it's common to want to control services.  Usually it's done through reduced permissions for users though.

Comment: An administrator is always going to be able to kill your service. If you're trying prevent particular users from bouncing your service, use group permissions.

Comment: @Samuel Neiff and razlebe, Thanx thats why I love Stack Overflow..One Upvote from my side :)

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to accomplish this that I can recommend.

1. **Permissions**.  Normal users should not have permissions to start/stop services.  If they do and are not administrators, you can at least remove permissions to start/stop the particular service you want to protect.  http://msmvps.com/blogs/erikr/archive/2007/09/26/set-permissions-on-a-specific-service-windows.aspx
2. **Restart**.  You can have a scheduled task to automatically restart the service if it is stopped.  Again, you can use permissions to make sure the scheduled task is not modified.  You can even run the task remotely as long as the target computer is on the network.

Answer (score 0):

Would you want some software installed on your PC to prevent you from starting or stopping it and just automatically forcing it to run....? I don't think so, this is a bad idea and am pretty sure security settings in windows will not allow this...

Comment: This does not answer the question.  It's a comment.  And one I disagree with.  There are legitimate reasons for wanting to do this.  Being a user does not necessarily mean it's "your" computer.

Comment: the original question does not draw any distinction between users or administrators and refers to the "service itself not be controllable" - specifically the comment "all working done by coding when we start the computer" - so I stand by what I said originally. That being said, with further clarification on the users vs admins side I also agree completely with what you are saying and if he is looking for user vs admin rights assignments then your answer is spot on.. +1 from me :-)

Comment: I would agree the original question could be worded better with more explanation.  This is one of those questions that requires a bit of magical insight and programming-clairvoyance.